# Using Karma to test Javascript on mobile devices

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm working on a project where we create a web-app and right now we run our unit-tests on our desktop browsers. However someone on the team expressed their concern with us not doing unit-testing on the mobile browsers the app is supposed to run on.

Is there a way to run jasmine tests using karma on mobile devices, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few companies that have infrastructure for this. One I saw a presentation from is http://appurify.com/. Googling around there are a few others.
I am sure each is different, but generally there is a VM that runs on the device, and you can tunnel to it and run unit, load, network, etc tests.

No relationship with appurify. Just happen to hear of them.

cheers-
Dustin